# Default Unity Sky box changed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox

so whenever I load up a new project in unity3d, the skybox is default to blue solid color,unlike how it originally was with a skybox with clouds and a sun in the sky, **how do I set it back so the default skybox is the original one that unity comes with**

*thank you in advanced* **;)**

Update: here is a picture of what it looks like

[[image: how it looks[1]]

vs what it should look like:

[image: How it should look]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ***MainCamera*** GameObject change ***solid color*** (in ***Camera*** component) to ***skybox***.

Go to ***Lighting*** tab >> ***Scene*** >> ***Environment*** ***Lighting*** >> ***Skybox*** and choose ***Default-Skybox*** material.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you taking project in 2D in unity .So you have to put skybox manually. And when you take the project in 3D in unity the skybox is default come in the scene. Please take new project in  Unity and select 3D you will find the skybox is coming by default 
thanx